# Apache POI: Elegant way to set borders to a column which contains different styles

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm dynamically creating a new xlsx file using apache-poi. Any column can contain different value types (Numbers, Strings, Booleans, ...). While inserting data into the poi document I set CellStyles depending on the type of the data:

```
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleString;
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleNumber;
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleDate;
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleHeader;
```

This is how my header rows look like:

```
|   |   |   | Shared Header |
| H1| H2| H3|SH1|SH2|SH3|SH4|
```

There are "simple" headers and "shared headers" which contain "sub headers". Shared headers reside in merged cells.

No I'd like to have a left border at column `SH1` and a right border at column `SH4` to emphasize the grouping. But as any column could contain a mix of all cellstyles, it seems like I have to create CellStyles like

```
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleString;
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleStringBorderLeft;
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleStringBorderRight;
//and so on for the other styles...
```

Furthermore there could be nested shared header which I'd like to distinguish by different border sizes. So I'd need something like

```
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleString;
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleStringBorderLeftThickLine;
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleStringBorderRightThickLine;
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleStringBorderLeftThinLine;
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleStringBorderRightThinLine;
//and so on for the other styles...
```

Is there a more elegant way to set the borders of the column regardless of the already existing style?

**Edit**

Although I prefer a clean and simple approach and that for to minimize the number of created styles, I stumpled upon the [HSSFOptimiser](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFOptimiser.html) which removes duplicate cellstyles. I didn't know about that class. Even though I prefer avoiding this utility it fits the problem and deserves to be mentioned here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am nearing the end of an enhancement to POI that will let you fill out the values with their specific styles, then draw borders around them without having to manually create all the necessary styles for that. In the mean-time, there is a way to do it using `CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties()`. This lets you add a set of properties to the `CellStyle` that already exists for a cell.

From the POI Quick Guide for HSSF/XSSF:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();  // OR new HSSFWorkbook()
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// create your spreadsheet without borders
...

// create property set for vertical borders
properties.put(CellUtil.BORDER_LEFT, CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
properties.put(CellUtil.BORDER_RIGHT, CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);

// Apply the borders to a 3x3 region starting at D4
for (int ix=3; ix <= 5; ix++) {
  row = sheet.createRow(ix);
  for (int iy = 3; iy <= 5; iy++) {
    cell = row.createCell(iy);
    CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, properties);
  }
}
```

This allows you to basically fill in your spreadsheet, then draw the borders one cell at a time. Note if all your borders are similar (all THIN) then this will work for your entire range. But, if you wanted to draw MEDIUM borders around the outside of the table, you would have to create some additional property sets. Note, you don't have to use `createRow()` and `createCell()` for rows and cells that are already in your spreadsheet. This will work around merged cells.

Note: `CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties()` appeared in POI 3.14 and allows you to add multiple cell properties in a single shot which avoids the creation of multiple unused styles. The older `CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty()` sets a single property at a time and, as an unintended consequence, creates intermediate `CellStyle` objects in the spreadsheet which turn out never being used. This can be a problem in larger sheets.

Edit:
`PropertyTemplate` is a new object added in POI 3.15 which will allow you to define a group of borders for cells and stamp it onto any sheet you want to apply it to. This object is like creating a preprinted form to overlay the data. See the POI Spreadsheet quick guide for more information on how to use `PropertyTemplate`.

Comment: This solution sound great. Sadly I can't test it right now because I had to move on to another task... Will CellStyles be reused this way? In other words: Will a new CellStyle be created per encountered cell or per encountered cellStyle?

Comment: I just read through our dependency hierarchy: we are still using poi 3.9. But I think it would be acceptable to create unused intermediate styles using the old method `setCellStyleProperty`. There are few styles in total and the only modifications are 2 borders per cell at most. Having 30% unused styles is still better than having >30.000 pseudo-unique styles. My former question is obsolete now as I read through the source of `setCellStyleProperty` and found the part which is reusing already known styles. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens when you use `setCellStyleProperty` is that it retrieves the `CellStyle` from the cell, creates a mock `CellStyle` with the new property merged in, and attempts to find an equivalent `CellStyle` in the workbook. If one does not exist, a new `CellStyle` is created and applied to the cell. `setCellStyleProperties` allows doing this with a whole group of properties vs. the one at a time method. If you are creating vertical borders, you will end up with a bunch of unused styles with just a left border, or just a right border depending on the order you add the borders.

Comment: You can also use this to set other `CellStyle` properties like fills.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

So how about utilizing the hash of the POI objects for caching and keeping track of decorated objects. The other created CellStyles that are not being used will be thrown away by the garbage collection.

Here is our cache:

```
private Map<Integer, MyCellStyle> styleCache = new HashMap<>();
```

And our own CellStyle class

```
final class MyCellStyle implements Cloneable {
    private XSSFCellStyle xssfCellStyle;

    public MyCellStyle(XSSFCellStyle xssfCellStyle) {
        this.xssfCellStyle = xssfCellStyle;
    }

    @Override
    public MyCellStyle clone() {
        MyCellStyle clone = new MyCellStyle(xssfCellStyle);
        return clone;
    }

    public final MyCellStyle borderLeftMedium() {
        MyCellStyle result = clone();
        result.xssfCellStyle.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        return result;
    }

    ... further decorations

    public XSSFCellStyle getXSSFCellStyle() {
        return xssfCellStyle;
    }

}
```

now to avoid creating new objects we write a small function

```
private MyCellStyle getCellStyle(MyCellStyle targetStyle) {
    int targetHash = targetStyle.hashCode();
    if (styleCache.keySet().contains(targetHash)) {
        return styleCache.get(targetHash);
    } else {
        return styleCache.put(targetHash, targetStyle);
    }
}
```

then we can create the cells themselves like this:

```
public void createCells() {
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

    Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(1);

    MyCellStyle baseStyle = new MyCellStyle(
            (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle());

    MyCellStyle decoratedStyle = getCellStyle(baseStyle.borderLeftMedium());

    cell.setCellStyle(decoratedStyle.getXSSFCellStyle());

}
```

If the hashCode is not unique for the same properties of the MyCellStyle object we might have to override the hashCode function:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return hashValue;
}
```

and add the styles value within each of our decoration functions:

```
public final MyCellStyle borderLeftMedium() {
        MyCellStyle result = clone();
        result.xssfCellStyle.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        hashValue += XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM; // simplified hash
        return result;
    }
```

=======================

ORIGINAL:

I like to create decorating methods that add a certain aspect of a cell to a cell style. So at first you create your base style

```
public final XSSFCellStyle cellStyleStringBase = wb.createCellStyle();
```

and create decorator methods to create a certain style

```
public XSSFCellStyle addBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle style) {
    XSSFCellStyle result = style.clone();
    result.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    return result;
}
```

Now, if you want to avoid to create new objects, you will still have to keep the cellStyles in own variables, you will not be able to avoid that, but from my experience the performance is sufficient if you simply decorate your cells like this

```
cell1.setCellStyle(addBorderLeft(cellStyleStringBase);
cell2.setCellStyle(addBorderRight(addBorderRight(cellStyleStringBase));
...
```

If you decorate with a lot of styles it makes sense to create your own CellStyle Class

```
public final MyCellStyle implements Cloneable {

    private XSSFCellStyle xssfCellStyle;

    public MyCellStyle(XSSFCellStyle xssfCellStyle) {
         this.xssfCellStyle = xssfCellStyle;
    }

    @Override
    public MyCellStyle clone() {
        MyCellStyle clone = new MyCellStyle(this.xssfCellStyle);
        return clone;
    }

    public final MyCellStyle borderLeftMedium() {
        return this.clone().setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    }

    public final MyCellStyle borderRightThick() {
        ...

}
```

you can then build your style in a better readable manner:

```
MyCellStyle base = new MyCellStyle(cellStyleStringBase);    
cell1.setCellStyle(base
    .addBorderLeftMedium()
    .addBorderRightThick()
    .addBorderBottomThin());
```

untested, but I hope it helps.

Comment: If I'd create new styles for each bordered cell I'd end up with tens of thousands of redundant cellstyles. For a number of reasons this is not acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. But as it still relies on creating new styles for each decoration this solution is not acceptable either.

Comment: This will create many, many, many instances of identical CellStyle and will increase the size of the excel-file.

Comment: Caching seems to be the answer indeed. Nevertheless I don't feel comfortable creating unique hashes by hand. The domain of cellstyles seems to be quite huge, so int might be way to small to ensure uniqueness. I will adopt yours and @Christoph-Tobias Schenke idea and create a custom key object for the map (which will internally override hash and equals)

Comment: Before finding this topic I've just created something similar like this. I've created a `CellStyleBuilder` class (builder pattern) which can create cell styles in a readable manner. And it caches already created cell styles in a map. Key of the map is a simple string which contains all properties of the cell style plus a delimiter to separate the values. This works very well for me and creation of cell styles became much easier.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned it is not good to create thousands and thousands of similiar cell-style-objects. in my project i created a simple "style-helper" class which has a map in it, which is aware of all existing style-instances

```
private Workbook workbook;
private HashMap<String, CellStyle> styleMap = new HashMap<>();

public CellStyle getStyle(Font font, ExcelCellAlign hAlign, ExcelCellAlign vAlign, boolean wrapText, ExcelCellBorder border, Color color, ExcelCellFormat cellFormat) {

    //build unique which represents the style
    String styleKey = ((font != null) ? font.toString() : "") + "_" + hAlign + "_" + vAlign + (wrapText ? "_wrapText" : "") + ((border != null) ? "_" + border.toString() : "") + "_"
            + styleKeyColor + (cellFormat != null ? "_" + cellFormat.toString() : "");

    if (styleMap.containsKey(styleKey)) {
        //return existing instance from map
        return styleMap.get(styleKey);
    } else {
        //create new style from workbook
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();


        // set all formattings to new cellStyle object
        if (font != null) {
            cellStyle.setFont(font);
        }

        // alignment
        if (vAlign != null) {
            cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(vAlign.getAlign());
        }

        //... snip ...

        //border
        if (border != null) {
            if (border.getTop() > BorderFormatting.BORDER_NONE) {
                cellStyle.setBorderTop(border.getTop());
                cellStyle.setTopBorderColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);
            }

            //... snip ...
        }

            if (color != null) {
                XSSFColor xssfColor = new XSSFColor(color);
               ((XSSFCellStyle)cellStyle).setFillForegroundColor(xssfColor);
            }
        }
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        styleMap.put(styleKey, cellStyle);

        return cellStyle;
    }
}
```

The parameter ExcelCellAlign is a simple enum which encapsulates the values for CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT, CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT, ...
ExcelCellBorder  is similiar to the Align. Just hide the values :-)
ExcelCellFormat is a enum which holds default-patterns for fortmatting the value.

I hope this is a good start for your own implementation. Feel free to ask if something is not clear